# Find all values of $c$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{c}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find all values of $c$ for which $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{c}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ converges.

I know that the series in question converges when $c=1$, but I have no concrete way to find all such values of $c$ for which this is true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write the summands as

$$\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]+\frac{c-1}{n}.$$

With this observation, it's easy to see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{c}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{N+1}+(c-1)\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}.$$

We know the harmonic series diverges, so this converges iff $c=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Combine the fractions:

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} {c(n+1)-n\over n(n+1)}=\sum_{n\ge 1}{(c-1)n+1\over n(n+1)}$$

Then comparing with the harmonic series shows only c=1 works.

Answer (score 2):

By comparison test, you may see that the series is convergent only when $c=1$, for otherwise it behaves the same as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: oh .. its already answered .. sorry my internet connection went off for few minutes